# Breeze NotMapped (Database) properties - not working

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, breeze

This is actually reposting a question that already exists but I don't think it was properly understood and for us is really important to know if is possible or if it will be:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079703/how-would-one-go-with-saving-a-complex-object-graph-as-xml-in-sql-database-whil

So, what we would like to know is how do we get to transfer from Breeze to server NON MAPPED TO DB entities/properties. For example, let's consider XML (I would't want to generate xml in JS, but I do have XML db columns that need to be populated from complex forms - so we will collect the data in Breeze/KO, will transfer it to server and on server will process and generate the XML, from the NON MAPPED Entities/Properties).

P.S.
I see there is already a NODB approach (http://www.breezejs.com/samples/nodb), so would be really nice if we would be able to make the 2 approaches work together (EF + NODB)

Answer (score 0):

As of Breeze v 1.3.6, there is now an EntityInfo.UnmappedValuesMap property available during the save that exposes all of the unmapped properties on any entity being saved.

Comment: Caveat: If you plan to use UnmappedValuesMap for something that updates entities server-side just before save, first read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146964

Answer (score -1):

Providing I'm understanding your question correctly, any properties declared as 'unmapped' on a breeze entity **do** get transferred to the server on a save for exactly this purpose.  You can intercept and work with this data within the server side BeforeSaveEntity and BeforeSaveEntities methods.

There is more info here regarding "unmapped" properties:

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already read that and if you'll check "Whither the unmapped property value?" you'll see it sais "The values of unmapped properties are not transmitted to the service."