# Compile error code when using a custom property on my entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, breeze

I found the following code here: [Breeze BeforeSaveEntityonly only allows update to Added entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146964/breeze-beforesaveentityonly-only-allows-update-to-added-entities) in the second answer. As fas as I understand it cannot work (as-is) because the property `ModificationDate` is not a known property of a generic Entity. I got a compile error `object does not contain a definition for 'ModificationDate' and no extension method 'ModificationDate' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found`

```
protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo)  
{
  if(entityInfo.EntityState== EntityState.Modified)
  {
     var entity = entityInfo.Entity;
     entityInfo.OriginalValuesMap.Add("ModificationDate", entity.ModificationDate);
     entity.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
  }
}
```

[image]

We should proceed like this:

```
protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo)  
{
  if(entityInfo.EntityState== EntityState.Modified)
  {
     Product entity = (Product)entityInfo.Entity;
     entityInfo.OriginalValuesMap.Add("ModificationDate", entity.ModificationDate);
     entity.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
  }
}
```

Then with this modified version of the code, the entity named `Product` has a property named `ModificationDate` and then everything compiled well.

**My question:** what if we still want to use a generic entity (using the `var` declaration) because we would like to use this code for different entity (Product, Clients, ...). Is it possible?

Hope my question is clear enough.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a job for generics. My own project does something like this; have a base class that has your `ModificationDate` properties and anything else that's common, and then `protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity<T>(EntityInfo entityInfo) where T : MyBaseClass` and use `T` instead of `Product`.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I'll flesh this out into a fuller answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the c# 'dynamic' keyword.  This code should work as long as the entity (of whatever type) has a "ModificationDate" property.

```
protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo)  
{
  if(entityInfo.EntityState== EntityState.Modified)
  {
     var entity = (dynamic)entityInfo.Entity;
     entityInfo.OriginalValuesMap.Add("ModificationDate", entity.ModificationDate);
     entity.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
  }
}
```